# Find distinct TimeSpan duration from a list of TimeSpans

Tags: c#, timespan

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to process a list of TimeSpan objects without having a lot of code which still doesn't seem to cover all eventualities, tbh, I think I've gone a bit code/logic blind now!

I have a list of TimeSpans of which overlaps will likely occur, but I need a list of TimeSpans which have no overlaps, but cover the whole duration of all TimeSpans.

For example (please note, dates are in ddMMyyyy format):

```
TS1: 01/01/2020 to 01/02/2020 (1 month)
TS2: 01/03/2020 to 01/05/2020 (2 months)
TS3: 01/04/2020 to 01/07/2020 (3 months with a 1 month overlap with TS2)
TS4: 01/10/2020 to 01/12/2020 (2 months)
TS5: 01/09/2020 to 01/01/2021 (4 months with a 2 month overlap with TS4)
```

So in this case I would expect to get 3 TimeSpans:

```
TSA: 01/01/2020 to 01/02/2020 (1 month - same as TS1 as there are no overlaps)
TSB: 01/03/2020 to 01/07/2020 (4 months - combination of TS2 and TS3)
TSC: 01/09/2020 to 01/01/2021 (4 months - combination of TS4 and TS5, technically only TS5 as TS4 is fully encompassed by TS5)
```

I've tried researching an algorithm online, but without any luck.

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't optimized at all, but *semantically* you can do this by adding the chunks and looking for overlaps, then merging those overlaps; something like:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

static class P
{

    static void Main()
    {
        var results = new List<(DateTime From, DateTime To)>();

        Add("01/01/2020", "01/02/2020");
        Add("01/03/2020", "01/05/2020");
        Add("01/04/2020", "01/07/2020");
        Add("01/10/2020", "01/12/2020");
        Add("01/09/2020", "01/01/2021");

        // SEE BELOW, IMPORTANT
        results.Sort(); // initial sort
        while (MergeOneOverlap()) { }
        foreach (var range in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{range.From:dd/MM/yyyy} - {range.To:dd/MM/yyyy}");
        }

        bool MergeOneOverlap()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
            {
                var x = results[i];
                for (int j = i + 1; j < results.Count; j++)
                {
                    var y = results[j];
                    if (x.Intersects(y))
                    {
                        results[i] = x.Merge(y);
                        results.RemoveAt(j);
                        results.Sort(); // retain sort while making progress
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        void Add(string from, string to)
            => results.Add(
                (DateTime.ParseExact(from, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                DateTime.ParseExact(to, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
    }
    static bool ContainsInclusive(this (DateTime From, DateTime To) range, DateTime when)
    => when >= range.From && when <= range.To;

    static bool Intersects(this (DateTime From, DateTime To) x, (DateTime From, DateTime To) y)
        => x.ContainsInclusive(y.From) || x.ContainsInclusive(y.To) || y.ContainsInclusive(x.From) || y.ContainsInclusive(x.To);

    static (DateTime From, DateTime To) Merge(this (DateTime From, DateTime To) x, (DateTime From, DateTime To) y)
        => (x.From < y.From ? x.From : y.From, x.To > y.To ? x.To : y.To);

}
```

If this is for large amounts of data, you'd have to look into being much smarter to avoid an O(N^3) problem. It *may* help to merge every add, if that will often keep the number of items down.

It may also be possible to reduce the complexity to O(N^2) and merging purely forwards (i.e. don't break on successful merge), but I haven't applied enough thinking to see about the implications of that. And O(N^2) is still pretty bad.

For large data, using a sorted list may help, so you can do a binary search on the start dates to find the insertion point. That is getting more complex than I care to write here, though.

---

I'm 95% sure that this is also fine, i.e. O(N^2):

```cs
        MergeOverlaps();
        foreach (var range in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{range.From:dd/MM/yyyy} - {range.To:dd/MM/yyyy}");
        }

        void MergeOverlaps()
        {
            results.Sort();
            for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
            {
                var x = results[i];
                for (int j = i + 1; j < results.Count; j++)
                {
                    var y = results[j];
                    if (x.Intersects(y))
                    {
                        results[i] = x = x.Merge(y);
                        results.RemoveAt(j--);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This was (almost) exactly what I needed! I'm just getting a few 'off-by-one' errors in my unit tests which I assume is going to be down to the end dates of a period being excluded.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try a brute force search or a depth-first search algorithm.

First you sort the timespans by starting date.

**BRUTE FORCE:**
You try all combinations and score them by overlap/not overlap, and you probably want to score them by how much of the total timespan is covered.

**DEPTH-FIRST-SEARCH:**
Write a recursive algorithm that start by adding the first interval and then add more interval and backtracks whenever an overlap occur.